# Regex get value between bracket and comma

Tags: regex, linux, unix, grep

I have a few strings like these:

> new google.maps.LatLng(52.80359, -4.7127),
>
> new google.maps.LatLng(53.80645306, -5.45455287),
>
> new google.maps.LatLng(51.8035914546, -4.7123622894287),

I need to get both the longitude and latitude, so one regex for each number, the - symbol needs including where possible.

I have tried a few tools online but none seem to pickup on a decent pattern

Comment: What flavor of regex? What programming language are you doing this in? What regex patterns have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use grep `grep -oE '[-0-9]+\.[0-9]+'`

```
$ echo "new google.maps.LatLng(52.80359, -4.7127)," | grep -oE '[-0-9]+\.[0-9]+'
52.80359 
-4.7127

$ echo "new google.maps.LatLng(53.80645306, -5.45455287)," | grep -oE '[-0-9]+\.[0-9]+'
53.80645306 
-5.45455287

$ echo "new google.maps.LatLng(51.8035914546, -4.7123622894287)," | grep -oE '[-0-9]+\.[0-9]+'
51.8035914546 
-4.7123622894287
```

`Grep` is the command line tool for matching lines in files *(or stdout)* against a particular pattern, the `-o` is tells grep to display on the part of the line that matches (by default grep displays the whole line that matches the given pattern). The `-E` tell grep to use grep to use [extended regexp](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Extended-regexps.html).

The `regexp` pattern `[-0-9]` matches either a minus sign `-` or a `digit` the following `+` says repeated the previous item one or more times *i.e* in `abc123xyz` match `123` not just `1` the `\.` matches the decimal place we have to escaped with `\` because a single `.` matches any character in `regexp` then match any digits after the decimal place using `[0-9]+` again.

See the [reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html) for more information on `regular expressions`.

Answer (score 1):

I would use this approach:

```
LatLng\((-*\d+\.*\d+),\s(-*\d+\.*\d+)\)
```

While it matches more than what you probably need, it places the latitude in capture group 1 and the longtitude in capture group 2, both excluding the surrounding parantheses' and the comma.

See it in action here: http://regexr.com?32od6

Answer (score 1):

in C# use [Regex.Match](http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-match) as follows:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
...
Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"([-]?\d+(?:[.]\d+)?)\D+?([-]?\d+(?:[.]\d+)?)");
if (match.Success)
{
  string Lat = match.Groups[1].Value;
  string Lng = match.Groups[2].Value;
}
```